# "Class constructor Parser cannot be invoked without 'new'" in deploying React application

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

Getting following error in deploying React App by "npm run build". But the same application works with "npm start".

**Error**:
Class constructor Parser cannot be invoked without 'new'

[image]

App.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import axios from "../node_modules/axios";

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      switcharray: [],
      name: "React",
      SelectedSwitch: "not selected"
    };
    this.onChangeValue = this.onChangeValue.bind(this);
  }

  onChangeValue(event) {
    // console.log(event.target.value);
    this.setState({
      SelectedSwitch: event.target.value
    });
  }
  
  async postData () {
    try {
```

**Package.json**

[image]

**debug log**

[image]

Comment: What's inside of `index.js`?

Comment: This sounds like a problem with your `build` script, not with the code that is deployed.

Comment: Hi @HaoWu: ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

Comment: Hi @Bergi, I'm new to this, is it possible to update build script?

Comment: Sure is. You haven't shown it to us though, we have no idea what you're using. You'll find in your package.json what `npm run build` is calling.

Comment: Hi @Bergi, I've attached the package.json

Comment: It seems we don't have enough information to know what's happening. Could you provide the debug log provided from the build? In the console it says. "A complete log of this run can be found in".

Comment: Hi @Kunukn, I've attached the debug log, Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Provide your index.js content, and there is no need to use super() function in your App.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was fixed after adding following dependency to package.json

"postcss": "7.0.32"